# Error when I try to re-install package after deleting it

Tags: package, install

I used `package-install` to install the *pamparam* package. It worked. But in playing with it, I got it into a weird state and decided to uninstall and re-install. I uninstalled by deleting its dir in `.emacs.d/elpa`.

Now when I try to re-install, I get the following compile log:

```
In pamparam-update-card:
pamparam.el:513:51:Warning: attempt to inline `pamparam-spit' before it was defined
pamparam.el:513:51:Warning: attempt to inline `pamparam-spit' before it was defined
pamparam.el:566:1:Error: Symbol's function definition is void: cl--do-arglist
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but have you tried restarting Emacs?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted emacs several times as I worked on this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to load `cl-lib.el`. But the package autoloads should have taken care of that and probably the warnings as well. If no one provides a satisfactory answer here you might want to consider contacting the package maintainer.

Comment: Did you update Emacs between the initial install and the failed attempts?

Comment: @YoungFrog No, haven't updated Emacs.